# Laravel 5 - View [app] not found

Tags: laravel-5

I used:Laravel API/Scaffold/CRUD Generator for laravel 5, 
I generate 1 CRUD, but not working.

This is the error:

```
ErrorException in FileViewFinder.php line 140:
View [app] not found. (View: C:\wamp\www\laravel\resources\views\istvans\index.blade.php)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Does the index.blade.php include an `@extends('app')` or similar blade method? The error is telling you it can't find the `app.blade.php` file inside your view directory.

Comment: I created: app.blade.php and now problem is gone.. ty for answer

Answer (score 1):

Create an empty `app.blade.php` and put this:

```html
<html>
<head>
    @section('head')
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    @show
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    @yield('content')
</div>

@section('footer_scripts')
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
@show
</body>
</html>
```